# How to prevent showing the elements of the page at the page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a page that has many components like:

1. text boxes.
2. labels.
3. images.
4. forms.

and all of these are depending on the url parameter. Thus, in the page load, i got sure that the parameter is existed and I validate its value according to my business rules.

I want if that url is not existed, to show a message error.

I tried this:

```
Response.Write("Please don't change anything in the URL");
```

It works good, but **my problem:** is that the other elements in the page are showing as well, i need not to show the other elements.

is that possible? or I should go to each element and make the `visibility` property as `false`?

Comment: have you tried grouping your elements into a container and then hiding / disabling them.. instead of individual elements

Comment: This is quite crude, however, if you don't want to show anything except for that message. Call `Response.End();` after your `Response.Write...`

Comment: @Candide from a user perpective: wouldn't it be much more elegant to not only show that message but rendering the usual page plus that message and all other relevant elements hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Page_Load` or `Page_Init` you can check whether some condition is met regarding the query string. Calling `Response.End();` will stop the execution of the page events. So in summary:

```
protected void Page_Init (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsQueryStringValid(Request.QueryString))
    {
        Response.Write("Please don't change anything in the URL");
        Response.End();
        // OR
        // Response.Redirect("~/QueryStringModifiedError.aspx");
    }
}
```